# Sitecore Powershell Workflow Actions Not Executing

Tags: powershell-extensions, workflow

I have been working to get a Powershell script to execute through a workflow action in Sitecore and I'm running into an issue. Previously I was able to insert a new Powershell action from the provided template. Having it as a direct child of a Workflow state worked pretty well. When moving my content item to that workflow state, I got the "script running" dialog and things behaved accordingly. Made total sense and worked pretty well out of the box for me. Good directions were provided here:
https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/v/v4.5.0/workflows.html

I noticed when I moved this over to my production environment, the Powershell workflow action wouldn't run. I checked and my production environment was on (SPE) 4.3. My dev environment was still on 4.1. Just to see, I upgraded my dev environment to 4.5 and encountered the same issue of the action not running. Nothing in the logs that I could find.

Reading the release notes, it says there were some pretty significant security updates for 4.3. My going theory is that my workflow actions were previously mis-configured in regards to permissions and security but ran anyway. Now that there's a security update, what can I troubleshoot to help solve the problem?

What I tried:

- I configured workflow command execute access on the Powershell Action item and assigned it to the right user group.
- I've tried using a variety of accounts (admin and non) to pass the item into the workflow state.
- I've tried making the action a direct child of a workflow command.

I'm on sitecore version 8.0 update 6.

Thanks for your time. Any pointers are appreciated! Given that 4.5 has the most up-to-date security, I would like to use that version.

Comment: Did you disable the password security feature on your dev machine to see if the issue is still encountered? You can patch the settings to "Allow".

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, Michael. You mean patching security for SPE itself? I just patched it with the UAC block from [here](https://alan-null.github.io/2017/01/spe-dev-config). I saw the intended results but my Powershell Workflow Action still wouldn't run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the error was introduced while refactoring for [#757](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/757).

The templates **PowerShell Script** and **PowerShell Script Workflow Action** both contain a field called *Script*.

Unfortunately, for the **PowerShell Script** item the field contains the script text while the **PowerShell Script Workflow Action** item field contains an item reference (Droplink).

[image: Workflow Action]

The fix actually requires a new build. Release 4.6 should include [#911](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/911) to address this.

#### Update

SPE 4.6 has been released and includes addresses this issue.